# "Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5" while the iPhone 5 launch image is included

Tags: ios, xcode6, app-store-connect

I have an iOS app that supports iOS 7 and iOS 8. There is a `LaunchScreen.xib` file for iOS 8 and a LaunchImage asset for iOS 7 in the asset catalogs. I included all the required launch images with the right sizes (`iPhone Portrait 2x`: 640px x 960px and `iPhone Portrait Retina 4`: 640px x 1136px). But when I submit the app to iTunes Connect I get the "Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5" error.

This are the settings that I used for the LaunchImage asset:
[image: This are the settings that I used for the LaunchImage asset]

Comment: Are you sure you're in 64bits?

Comment: @Zil Yes, because when I disable iOS 7 support, submitting to iTunes Connect works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem: My iPhone 5 launch image was corrupted, I replaced the images with a new one and the problem was solved. The strange thing is that the asset catalogs previewed the corrupted image without any problems (and Mac Preview too). But the problem is solved :).